# Using multiple for tags in tables with django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm fairly new to Django, and am working on a project where I have items appended to multiple lists and would like to display them in a table. I am using the for tag as there is quite a few items in each list. However, when i run my code, the first item on the list repeats over and over, then the second item repeats over and over, and so on. I have a feeling its because i used multiple for tags. Heres my code:

```
<table>
{% for x in result.netIncomeAr %}
{% for y in result.d2 %}    
<tr>    
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
    <td>{{ y }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Any ideas where I went wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop should use the outer loop variable:

```
{% for x in result.netIncomeAr %}
    {% for y in x.d2 %}
```

UPD (after looking at the `result` variable):

You need to change the `result` variable passed into the template, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to join two lists:

```
result = zip(df['Date'], df['Net Income'])
return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"result": result},  context)
```

Then, in the template iterate over the `result` this way:

```
<table>
    {% for x in result %}
    <tr>    
        <td>{{ x.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: I've edited my code to match this, but now I get no output at all. I'm not sure if it matters, but x and y are stored in different arrays.

Comment: @nawawaz ok, could you show the value of the `result` variable? At least the relevant part of it.

Comment: Ok, the result lives in my views.py, which has grown to be quite large. [Here is the relevant part](http://pastebin.com/jMXpPKhT).